# how to avoid empty spaces when I fill a grid in html5?

Tags: javascript, css, html

how to avoid empty spaces when I fill a grid, I would like to use all the spaces.

In this example how can I introduce the div with the number 4 in the space under the div with the plus and avoid the empty spaces in the grid, the div with the number 4 is down and outline of the grid.

This is my code:

html

```
<div id="grid">
   <div class="cell2x3" >1</div>
   <div class="cell1x1" >+</div>
   <div class="cell2x2" >2</div>
   <div class="cell1x3" >3</div>
   <div class="cell2x1" >4</div> 
   <div class="cell1x2" >5</div> 
</div>
```

css:

```
#grid {
width: 600px;
height: 300px;  
outline: 1px solid blue;
}

.cell {
    outline: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

.cell2x3 {
    outline: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
}

.cell1x1 {
    outline: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

.cell2x2 {
    outline: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}

.cell1x3 {
    outline: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    width: 300px;
}
.cell2x1 {
    outline: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100px;
}

.cell1x2 {
    outline: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

This is the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/urisito/1e2cfupq/1/)

Comment: This is the sort of thing that Packery and Masonry do. Have a look.

Comment: wait, am I understanding right: do you mean that you want to put the div up and right below the + so the 4 is like a full grid... like a sudoku grid.... do you intend to hardcode this or like allow the computer to fit in like a puzzle...

Comment: so  like this: http://jsfiddle.net/1e2cfupq/3/

Comment: yes i want that, is something like a puzzle

Comment: +1 to packery then, if you want to do it quickly and simply. If you want to do it yourself, you'll need to look up bin-packing algothrim and implement that

Comment: yeah I need implement that to build a grid with many variants

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the float. 
type in

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

to remove the float of the the current divs and effectively create a new line.

Comment: There are better ways to clear floats without extra markup. Where did you intend to use that? Here's a starter fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/nxzkkruh/

Comment: this isn't what the OP is looking for at all

Answer (score 0):

Solution using jQuery:

1-Take the div element with the number 4

```
var div_4 = $('#grid').children('div').eq(4);
```

2-Remove div element whit number 4 from the DOM

```
div_4.remove();
```

3-Add div element whit number 4 after the div with the plus

```
div_4.insertAfter($('#grid').children('div').eq(1));
```

This can be more optimized.

When using the jQuery **remove()** method, you need to keep two things in mind:

1. While the elements selected are removed from the DOM using **remove()** , they have not been removed from the jQuery wrapper set. That means in theory you could continue operating on them and even add them back into the DOM if desired.
2. This method will not only remove the elements from the DOM, but it will also remove all event handlers and internally cached data that the elements removed might have contained.

if you want a solution without use jQuery let me know....

Comment: I tried it with your code but the div with number 4 was moved to the right and I need the div element with number 4 under the the div with the plus.

Comment: you're right, I didn't considered the CSS properties of elements...i couldn't   see yet the example from jsfiddle.net because my connection is bad but if you only want put the <div> with the 4 element under the div with the + add this css rules to the div element with 4: `postion:relative;top:-100px;`